# angularjs + spring mvc + json post request

Tags: json, spring, angularjs, spring-mvc, post

I've been doing some research on the web regarding my problem, and I feel that my code reflects what's written in most of the examples - and yet, it still doesn't work. Thus my question.

Long story short, I want to send POST request to add new item to some "backend". For REST API I use Spring MVC, for sending the request I use $http from AngularJS

That's how I invoke the POST request

```
    $scope.testAddItem = function(){
    $http({
        'url' : 'addNewItem',
        'method' : 'POST',
        'headers': {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
        'data' : $scope.newItem
    }).success(function(data){
        $scope.marketForm.texts.push({'text' : data.text});
    })
}
```

Which maps to the proper URL. Problem is that I get the following response

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 400 BAD_REQUEST</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 400</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /poll/addNewItem/. Reason:
<pre>    BAD_REQUEST</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>
```

I get this error either when I click the button on the website, and when I'm testing it via some REST Client.

Dependencies I've included in my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

One note - sending other request via GET works.

My Controller class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class PollController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String mainPage(){
    return "poll";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/getNewElement")
public @ResponseBody
List<PollItem> getNewElement(){

    List<PollItem> listOfItems = new ArrayList<PollItem>(2);

    listOfItems.add(new PollItem("test 1"));
    listOfItems.add(new PollItem("test 2"));

    return listOfItems;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/addNewItem", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes =    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody PollItem addNewElement(@RequestBody PollItem pollItem){
    pollItem.setId(2); // I know it makes no logical sense, but it's just for testing.
    return pollItem;
}

}
```

Any clues ?

EDIT

After adding debug mode it seems that it's some JSON parsing problem

```
Method [public com.poll.model.PollItem com.poll.controller.PollController.addNewElement(com.poll.model.PollItem)]

    org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Unexpected character ('a' (code 97)): expected a valid value (number, String, arr
    ay, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
    at [Source: HttpInputOverHTTP@5ce15706; line: 1, column: 2]; nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('a' (code 97)): expected
    a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
    at [Source: HttpInputOverHTTP@5ce15706; line: 1, column: 2]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.read(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:179)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodAr
    gumentResolver.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:183)

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:157)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:738)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1045)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('a' (code 97)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null'
    )
    at [Source: HttpInputOverHTTP@5ce15706; line: 1, column: 2]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1433)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:521)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:442)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._handleUnexpectedValue(Utf8StreamParser.java:2090)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._nextTokenNotInObject(Utf8StreamParser.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser.nextToken(Utf8StreamParser.java:492)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2770)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2718)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1923)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:184)
    ... 38 more
```

EDIT2

It seems that it works, problem is that it supports only " (double quotes) where I want to use single-quotes. Is there any reason why I should double quotes always when doing JSON?

And what I should do change default behaviour of JSON mapper?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, to answer the question - issue was that I used badly formatted JSON. I should be using double-quotes instead of single quotes (which is basically follwoing JSON standard. I'm new to this and I was a little bit confused, because a lot of websites uses single quotes for their examples - like for instance google charts ).

```
{"id":10,"text":"smth smth"}
```

is good

```
{'id':10,'text':'smth smth'}
```

is **bad**:)

Answer (score 3):

That's true if your JSON is not mapped correctly with server side object then it will throw exception. I found very nice simple example here working exactly what you are looking for:

[AngularJS Post Spring MVC JSON Example](http://javahonk.com/angularjs-post-spring-mvc-json-example/)

[AngularJS Form Post Spring MVC JSON](http://javahonk.com/angularjs-form-post-spring-mvc-json/)

Comment: Please consider adding code examples in your answers, because links rot :)

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing the default constructor in your PollItem domain.

```
public class PollItem {
     public PollItem () {
     }
     //your rest of the codes
}
```

Add this and your code will work just fine.

You already have a constructor defined in PollItem, which is making it the default constructor. Therfore adding the dummy constructor will solve your problem

Comment: Can you please check your server log. There should be some messages regarding this bad request. If you can post it, I can help you further.

Comment: I'm running it via mvn -X jetty:run to see some debugging info, but sadly nothing comes up when I'm trying to access the POST method :/

Comment: Added some DEBUG info

Comment: There is a miss match between the json data you are sending and your POJO. That is the reason Jackson is not able to map the json to pojo. Check your json data using Firebug/Developer Tools with your Pojo structure. If you provide the json and pojo I can take a look as well.

Comment: try changing the content type of the request to "application/json; charset=UTF-8" and see what happens

Comment: Yes single quote json is non-standard. Also you should not used $http for sending post requests, its too clumsy. You should always use $resource by using injecting 'ngResource'. $resource will stringify your json, add appropriate headers, so you don't have to do all the stuff you have done in $http.