# Post request from angularjs to spring mvc controller

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to angularjs. I am trying to post a request from angularjs to spring controller. The request object is logged properly in angular but it reaches as null in controller.

I have been through the similar questions but they didn't worked out for me :

[getting null using angular post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35522101/getting-null-using-angular-post)

[angularjs-spring-mvc-json-post-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22881534/angularjs-spring-mvc-json-post-request)

[spring-angularjs-receiving-null-data-on-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31718216/spring-angularjs-receiving-null-data-on-server)

Controller.js :

```
$scope.addExpense = function (expense) {
        console.log("Received"+expense.amount+expense.description);

        var expenseDetail = {
            description:expense.description,
            amount:expense.amount,
            created:'',
            updated:'',
        };

        console.log("expense detail : "+JSON.stringify(expenseDetail));

        $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url     : 'addExpense1',
            data    : JSON.stringify(expenseDetail),
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }).success(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        }).error(function(response){
            console.log("Error : "+response.data);
        });
    };
```

Controller method :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "addExpense1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public List<ExpenseDetail> addExpense1(@RequestBody ExpenseDetailDTO expenseDetailDTO) {
    LOG.info("Request to add description : " + expenseDetailDTO.getDescription());
    if(expenseDetailDTO==null || expenseDetailDTO.getDescription()==null || expenseDetailDTO.getAmount()==null)
        return null;
    expenseService.addExpense(expenseDetailDTO);

    List<ExpenseDetail> expenseDetails = expenseService.getAllForToday();
    LOG.info("Expense Details fetched : " + expenseDetails.size());
    return expenseDetails;
}
```

On controller following log is printed :

```
Request to add description : null
```

I am not getting error anywhere. 
Kindly help me out.

Comment: How u solved this..?

Answer (score 0):

i had similar issue in the past using spring webmvc.

https://github.com/sombriks/rango-vote-spring/blob/master/src/main/java/rango/vote/RangoVoteController.java

What solved in my case was the addition of jackson-databind dependency and the proper configuration:

https://github.com/sombriks/rango-vote-spring/blob/master/build.gradle#L54

https://github.com/sombriks/rango-vote-spring/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml#L29

If possible, prefer spring + jersey over spring webmvc since you could use jaxb to properly map your data objects:

http://pastebin.com/TVsrJJm7

http://pastebin.com/jE7z1u3k

http://pastebin.com/39QDBgQD

Hope it helps